# JEXL3 - euler function

Tags: java, kotlin, jexl

Is it possible to parse functions with an `e` (as the euler function) in it? Such as:

```
x*e
```

I get `undefined variable e` with this:

```
var jexl = JexlBuilder().create()
var jexlEpxression = jexl.createExpression("x*e") //still works
var jexlContext = MapContext()
jexlContext.set("x",1.0)
jexlExpression.evaluate(jexlContext) // undefined variable e
```

Of course there could be this manual fix:

```
val containsE = "x*e".contains("e")
if(containsE)
   jexlContext.set("e",Math.E)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is.
JEXL does not check variable existence at script creation time; with JEXL3, you can determine which variables are used in a script (JexlScript) by calling the 'getVariables()' method.
More specifically, if 'e' is a variable that should always be accessible in your use case, I'd suggest systematically adding it to your context (or override context).